# log(x) DOMAIN ERROR C++ Builder

Tags: c++, math, graph, c++builder, logarithm

I must build graph with log(x) function, but builder show error "DOMAIN ERROR".
I think it's becouse log can't contain x , but I don't know how fix it.

```
......
int x0, y0 ,mash_x, mash_y;
float f(float x);
float f(float x)
{
        return log10(x) + 3;

}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 int xk(float mx)//komp
  {
   return floor(x0+mx*mash_x);
  }
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

   int yk(float my)//komp
  {
   return floor(y0-my*mash_y);
  }
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

 void drawgraf(float xmin,float xmax)
 {
   float x, y;
   int XK, YK;
   x = xmin;
   y = f(x);
   XK = xk(x);
   YK = yk(y);
   Form1->Image1->Canvas->Pen->Color = clRed ;
   Form1->Image1->Canvas->MoveTo(XK,YK);
   while(x<=xmax)
    {
      x = x+0.01;
      y = f(x);
      XK = xk(x);
      YK = yk(y);
      Form1->Image1->Canvas->LineTo(XK,YK);
    }
```

Can you help with this part of code ?

```
float f(float x)
    {
            return log10(x) + 3;

    }
```

How can I buld log10(x) + 3 without  "DOMAIN ERROR" ;
Thank's;

Comment: Use `log10f()`, not `log10()`. And make sure x is a positive number, e.g., `if (x>0.0) return log10f(x)+3.0; else /* error handling */ ;`. Also, meaningful function and variable names would improve the readability of your code.

Comment: thank you @squeamishOssifrage